# Error using MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback at page

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I am using `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` in a page autopostbackevent not fired in any controls like radiobutton,dropdownlist expect button control..
after removing `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` this one all event work fine...

Why? What reason?

```
// Before adding
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Alloc_Movement/AllocMov_Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AM_RequestForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="Alloc_Movement_AM_RequestForm" Title="RequestEntry - CoRMS " EnableEventValidation="false" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %> 

// After removing 

<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Alloc_Movement/AllocMov_Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AM_RequestForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="Alloc_Movement_AM_RequestForm" Title="RequestEntry - CoRMS " EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

Comment: have checked on different browsers .. IE , Chrome , Firefox ?

Comment: Show your source code of page.and which version you are using?

Comment: Before adding..<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Alloc_Movement/AllocMov_Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="AM_RequestForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="Alloc_Movement_AM_RequestForm" Title="RequestEntry - CoRMS "
    EnableEventValidation="false" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>  Afer removing                  <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Alloc_Movement/AllocMov_Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="AM_RequestForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="Alloc_Movement_AM_RequestForm" Title="RequestEntry - CoRMS "
    EnableEventValidation="false" %>

Answer (score 0):

Page directive - "MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" Will not work in

1. Framework 2.0 and
2. AjaxToolkit (ver 1.0.2....)